# Using directory resource inside Chef Provider LWRP

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, lwrp

I'm trying to use directory resource under Chef LWRP, but unable to access the attribute inside the resource block, is there a way to do it.
Or am I totally wrong and need different approach to achieve this.

`my-cookbook/providers/default.rb`

```
use_inline_resources

action :setup do
  directory node["#{@new_resource.name}"] do
    action :create
    not_if {node["#{@new_resource.name}"].include? "test"}
  end
end
```

The `@new_resource.name` on the line `not_if {node["#{@new_resource.name}"].include? "test"}` is evaluated as nilClass,

while it gets properly evaluated in `directory node["#{@new_resource.name}"] do` line

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At last, found it

When referring to variable inside another resource, we need to access it without @.

```
action :setup do
  new_resource = @new_resource
  directory node["#{@new_resource.name}"] do
    action :create
    not_if {node["#{new_resource.name}"].include? "test"}
  end
end
```

Thanks to @stajkowski ([GitHub](https://github.com/stajkowski/kickstart-lwrp/blob/master/providers/default.rb#L75))

Comment: And you should not use interpolation when you just call a variable neither. Btw, You code sounds really strange here and there's probably another approach to what you're after...

Comment: Hi @Tensibai. I hope you are right, there would be a better solution.

The use case is like, I have a recipe, which needs to be called with different attributes every time, and as chef does not call include_recipe more than once, I'm just making the recipe an LWRP (a copy paste of the recipe actually).

Its a long recipe, I passed only one resource to explain my problem.

Thank you so much.